# Rule of mutual exclusion: is the converse true?

Tags: physical-chemistry, spectroscopy, symmetry

There is a "famous" rule in spectroscopy,<sup>1</sup> that goes this way:

> If a compound is centrosymmetric, then its normal vibrational modes cannot be simultaneously IR and Raman active.

and this is simple enough to prove: for a vibrational mode to be IR active, it has to transform under the same irrep as (one of) the cartesian axes $x$, $y$ or $z$, which are all *ungerade*. For a vibrational mode to be Raman active, it has to transform under the same irrep as one of $(x^2, y^2, z^2, xy, yz, xz)$, and since $u \otimes u = g$, these irreps cannot be the same as the irreps of $(x,y,z)$. Hence, a vibrational mode, which transforms under a single irrep, cannot simultaneously satisfy both conditions at once.

However, I am curious about the converse statement.

> If a compound does not have any vibrational modes which are simultaneously IR and Raman active, is it *necessarily* centrosymmetric?

If the answer is *yes*, I would like a proof; if it is *no*, a counterexample, please.

(Just in case anybody is confused, because I am: A counterexample would be a molecule *without* a centre of inversion, which has no vibrational mode which is simultaneously IR and Raman active.)

---

<sup>1</sup> Famous enough for me to know, at least.

Comment: I just went through a number of common molecule point groups and in all of them that were note inversion-symmetric there was at least one irreducible representation that included a simple translational and a product mode. Looks like if there is a counterexmple it will be an extremely rare case.

Comment: Have a look at the point groups O (not $\ce{O_h}$) and $\ce{D_{5h}, C_{5h}}$. I will try and find a pic of O point group molecules.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at the point groups O (not $\ce{O_h}$) I, $\ce{D_{5h} and C_{5h}}$. A pic of an O point group molecule is shown below. The $\ce{c_2}$ axes are not shown. Taken from molecule-viewer.com web site. The molecule is 'vanadium hexaoxo phosphonato' or more properly $\ce{C8H24O30P8V^+Cl^-}$, octakis(μ 3-methylphosphonato)-hexaoxo-penta- vanadium(v)-vanadium(iv) chloride clathrate !!!

[image: vanadium O point group]

Edit: I checked a bit more and found ; $\ce{ S8 }$

Comment: One reference says "Number of Vibrational Active IR Bands: Only Rx, Ry, Rz, x, y, and z can be ir active" which would seem to rule out D5h and C5h.  http://chem.libretexts.org/Core/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry/Spectroscopy/Vibrational_Spectroscopy/Vibrational_Modes/Mode_Analysis another reference oppositely says "is Raman active if the symmetry is the same as
x2, y2, z2, or one of the rotational functions Rx, Ry, Rz" http://www.lasalle.edu/~prushan/IC-articles/lecture%204.pdf which would exclude O and I.

Comment: D5h, C5h, O and I are all fair counter examples if OP's statement "for a vibrational mode to be IR active, it has to transform under the same irrep as (one of) the cartesian axes x, y or z, which are all ungerade. For a vibrational mode to be Raman active, it has to transform under the same irrep as one of (x2 ,y2 ,z 2 ,xy,yz,xz)" is completely right, but not if one of those references is correct.

Comment: hi, Rx, Ry Rz do not refer to vibrations but to 'rotational' operators such as spin-orbit coupling and whole body rotations

Answer (score 9):

If there is a molecule of $O$ (as opposed to $O_h$) or $I$ (as opposed to $I_h$) symmetry, it would be such a counter example (no mode that is both IR and raman active, and not centrosymmetric).

http://symmetry.jacobs-university.de/cgi-bin/group.cgi?group=903&option=4

http://symmetry.jacobs-university.de/cgi-bin/group.cgi?group=905&option=4

Apparently a [snub cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snub_cube) is an example of the $O$ point group and in [Chemistry for the 21st Century](https://books.google.com/books?id=GQpieBwhxbcC&pg=PA145&dq=conforms%20to%20a%20snub%20cube&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiNpLiR57fPAhXDJCYKHZl0By8Q6AEIJTAB#v=onepage&q=conforms%20to%20a%20snub%20cube&f=false) it is stated:

> 9.5.2.5 Snub Cube (6) We have recently demonstrated the ability of six resorcin[4]arenes and eight water molecules to assemble in apolar media to form a spherical molecular assembly which conforms to a snub cube (Fig. 9.3)